# Global variables and constexpr (inline or not?)

Tags: c++, linker, inline, constexpr, one-definition-rule

If I have: a.hpp a.cpp and main.cpp includes a.hpp, and in a.hpp I write

```
template<typename T>
constexpr int num;
template<>
constexpr int num<float> = 1;
template<>
constexpr int num<double> = 2;
```

Do I risk defining the variable num multiple times both in a.o and main.o? Or is it declared inline? Shall I put template variables specializations inside a.cpp? What changes if I wrap a.hpp into a namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I risk defining the variable `num` multiple times both in a.o and main.o?

You do. For non-template variables, `constexpr` implies `const` and `const` at the namespace level implies internal linkage, but not for variable templates. It seems that this is underspecified in the standard. The current draft has the following

> [Note](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#note-1) 1: An instantiated variable template that has `const`-qualified type can have external or module linkage, even if not declared `extern`.

Experimentally, different compilers give them different linkages. For example, with GCC 9.3.0 and 10.2.0 `num<float>` has internal linkage:

> ```
> nm -C a.o
> ...
> 0000000000000004 r num<float>
> ```

but with Clang 10.0.0 it has external linkage:

> ```
> nm -C a.o
> ...
> 0000000000000000 R num<float>
> ```

As a result, if you try to include `a.hpp` in two compilation units, you'll get a link error with Clang.

---

> Or is it declared inline?

No, explicit `inline` is needed.

> What changes if I wrap a.hpp into a namespace?

I guess you're talking about an unnamed namespace. In this case each compilation unit is guaranteed to get its own (private) copy.

Comment: Ok, so this is only for template variables, strange. I was using g++-10 and it gave me no error as you said. I will declare them inline. Thanks.

Comment: @lucmobz It should fail with Clang (after you fix a compilation error due to uninitialized  `num<T>`).