# Global variables - When to use static, inline, extern, const, and constexpr

Tags: c++, constants, global-variables, linkage, c++-faq

There are plenty of questions and answers relating to C++ global variables, such as:

- [static and extern global variables in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055802)
- [Global variables and constexpr (inline or not?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65521040)
- [Is there any sense to declare static global variable as inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58101044)
- [Are global variables extern by default or is it equivalent to declaring variable with extern in global?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28610783)
- [Defining global constants in C++1z?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45710667)
- [Defining global constant in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268749)
- [inline static constexpr vs global inline constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71699928)

They all contain small fragments of information, such as how `inline` variables work in C++17 specifically, etc. Some of them also haven't aged well, since C++17 fundamentally changed the rules by introducing `inline` variables.

C++20 also introduces modules and module linkage, yet again making most content on StackOverflow out-of-date, or even obsolete.

**This Q&A is an attempt at unifying these questions, and at giving readers an overview that considers these version changes.**

#### Questions

- When do I use `static`, `inline`, `extern`, `const`, `constexpr` etc. for global variables?
- How does the answer change historically (before/after C++17, before/after C++20)?
- How does the answer change depending on where the global variable is located (header/source/module)?

Comment: First of all do not use global variables (so extern should not be needed at all), for global constanst in a header file it should be `inline constexpr <type>{value}`, for constants in a cpp file `constexpr <type>{value};`.  `const` is used for immutable arguments (and for member functions that do not change the state of an object). If you have global state use dependency injection.

Comment: Slight correction : for constants in a cpp file `static constexpr <type>{value};`

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think people have been told not to use global variables plenty enough, and if you do have a valid use case, then the question still remains how to implement it. `inline`/`static` `constexpr` also doesn't cover nearly everything, since the answer is going to be different in C++98, C++11, C++17, and C++20 (with modules).

Comment: Fair enough my answer is mainly about 17/20

Comment: I think it is worth it to mention that the context of where you are programming has a lot to do with how to answer these questions.  For example, I am currently working on code review for flight control software written in C.  They have a coding standard that any function file scoped is static.  That might not be necessary if you are building for windows, but in their environment, it is.  It is better to get a deep understanding of these terms so you can apply the best practices in your specific use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When do I use `static`, `inline`, `extern`, `const`, `constexpr` etc. for global variables?

### 0. Overview

| Global Variable Use Case | Constants | Non-Constants |
| --- | --- | --- |
| local to a single source file (i.e. declared and only used in a single file, not declared in a header) | `static const`, `static constexpr`<sup>(C++11)</sup>, or `const` in anonymous namespace<sup>(C++11)</sup> | `static`, or in anonymous namespace<sup>(C++11)</sup> |
| declared, not defined in a header, defined in a source file | `extern const` in header; `const` in source, or `constexpr`<sup>(C++11)</sup> in source | `extern` in header; plain in source |
| defined in a header, until C++17 | imitate `inline` with templates and `const` or `constexpr`<sup>(C++11)</sup>; or `enum` for integers only | imitate `inline` with templates |
| defined in a header, since C++17 | `inline const`, or `inline constexpr` | `inline` |
| local to a single module<sup>(C++20)</sup> | `const` or `constexpr`; optionally `inline` | optionally `inline` |
| exported by a module<sup>(C++20)</sup> | `export const` or `export inline constexpr` | `export`; optionally `inline` |

In all cases above, `constinit`<sup>(since C++20)</sup> may also be used, but not in combination with `constexpr`. `constinit const` has it uses too, and is not the same as `constexpr`.

*Note: the decision may also change based on whether the global variables are defined/used in dynamically linked libraries, and other factors.*

### 1. *Always* use ensure that *everything* local to one source file has internal linkage

First of all, if the global variable is declared in, and only used in a single source file, then it *must* have internal linkage.
A global variable has internal linkage when:

- it is marked `static`
- it is in an anonymous namespace<sup>(since C++11)</sup>
- it is `const` (or `constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup>, since `constexpr` implies `const`)

If it doesn't have internal linkage, then you could easily run into an ODR violation. The example below is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

```cpp
// a.cpp
int counter = 0;   // FIXME: surround with anonymous namespace, or add 'static'
// b.cpp
long counter = 0;  // FIXME: surround with anonymous namespace, or add 'static'
```

Making the variable `inline`<sup>(since C++17)</sup> does not solve this issue.
Internal linkage makes it safe, because the two `counter`s would be distinct in each TU.

### 2. If something is declared, but not defined in a header, make it `extern`

Sometimes, it's not important for everyone to have a definition. For example:

```cpp
// log.hpp
extern std::ofstream log_file;
// log.cpp
std::ofstream log_file = open_log_file();
```

It would be pointless to put the definition of `log_file` to be in a header, and thus visible everywhere. Very little can be gained in terms of performance, and it would force us to make `open_log_file()` visible everywhere too.

###### Note on `extern constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> or `extern const constinit`<sup>(since C++20)</sup>

Another valid but rare use case is `extern constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76486191)), i.e. `extern const` in a header, `constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> in a source.
If available, this is better expressed through `const constinit`<sup>(since C++20)</sup> in the source.

The purpose of this pattern is to avoid dynamic initialization for expensive-to-initialize look-up tables while keeping a header/source split.

### 3. If something is defined in a header, make it `inline`<sup>(since C++17)</sup>, or imitate `inline` with templates<sup>(until C++17)</sup>

Sometimes, it is important to have a definition everywhere, such as for global constants that should be inlined:

```cpp
inline constexpr float exponent = 1.25f;
```

###### Q: Do I really need `inline` in combination with `constexpr`?

Yes, you do. Consider the following example:

```cpp
constexpr float exponent = 1.25f; // OK so far, but dangerous

// note: 'const float&' might seem contrived because you could work with 'float'.
//       However, templates use const& everywhere, so it's very easy to
//       run into this case indirectly.
inline const float& foo(const float& x) {
    // IFNDR if the definition of foo appears in multiple translation units (TUs).
    return std::max(x, exponent);
}
```

This program may be ill-formed, no diagnostic required, because `exponent` has internal linkage (due to being `const`) and is a distinct object in every TU.
Each definition of `foo` may return a different reference to its own unique `exponent`, which is a violation of [[basic.def.odr] p14.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14.5)

###### Q: What can I do prior to C++17? `inline` variables don't exist yet.

A similar mechanism has always existed in the form of templates.

```cpp
// define a wrapper class template with a static data member
template <typename = void>
struct helper { static const float exponent; };
// define the static data member
template <typename T>
struct helper<T>::exponent = 1.25f;
// For convenience, make a reference with internal linkage to it.
// This is safe from ODR violations because
// [basic.def.odr] p14.5.2 has a special case for it, and
// this special case was retroactively applied to all C++ standards
// in the form of a defect report.
static constexpr float& exponent = helper<>::exponent;
// (static const float& prior to C++11)
```

Alternatively, specifically for scoped<sup>(since C++11)</sup> and unscoped enumerations, you can put the definition in a header without risk:

```cpp
inline constexpr int array_size = 100; // since C++17
enum { array_size = 100; };            // pre-C++17 alternative
```

### 4. Make *all* global variables `const` or even `constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> whenever possible

In addition to the rules in **1.**, **2.**, **3.**, *always* make things `const` when they can be.
This hugely simplifies ensuring correctness of your program, and enables additional compiler optimizations.

###### Q: What do I do if initialization is complicated?

Sometimes you can't just initialize a global with a simple expression, like here:

```cpp
std::array<float, 100> lookup;

void init() {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < lookup.size(); ++i) {
        lookup[i] = compute(i);
    }
}
```

However, don't *late-initialize*; instead use an immediately invoked lambda expression (IILE)<sup>(since C++11)</sup> or a regular function to perform initialization.

```cpp
constexpr std::array<float, 100> lookup = [] {
    decltype(lookup) result{};
    /* ... */
    return result;
}();
```

###### Q: What impact does `const` or `constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> have on linkage?

Making a global variable `const` or `constexpr`<sup>(since C++11)</sup> gives it internal linkage, but as explained in **3.**, this doesn't simplify anything for you.
You still have to worry about linkage and the ODR.

### 5. Static data members work differently

As seen in **3.**, static data members might not follow the same rules.
They have the same linkage as the class they belong to, with the following consequences:

- Static data members are quasi-`inline` in the case of class templates.
- `const` does not imply internal linkage for static data members.

Also, `constexpr` for static data members implies `inline`<sup>(since C++17)</sup>.